# Привилегия Меньше рекламы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии, реклама

На [странице параметров](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/) аккаунта есть секция "Реклама":

[image: описание]

При этом ссылка [Меньше рекламы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) должна бы вести на страницу описания соответствующей привилегии (как это сделано в [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)), но у нас такой привилегии в списке не значится, и т.о. ссылка ведет на общий список привилегий.

Привилегия и её описание должны быть явно добавлены в список.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эта привилегия была скрыта на SO.ru. Проблема заключалась в том, что это не учитывалось на странице настроек пользователя, а панель выбора отображалась независимо от этого факта. Это было в сборке rev `2016.11.16.4204`, так как это также было проблемой на других сайтах.

После разговора с [@NicolasChabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) я раскрыл привилегию на SO.ru, так как у вас есть специальное объявление для вопросов. Привилегия "Меньше рекламы" теперь отображается на странице [help/privileges](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), [справочная статья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) теперь также работает должным образом.

Оригинал:

> This privilege was hidden on SO.ru. The issue was with it not being taken into account on the users preferences page, and the opt in panel showing up regardless of the fact. That has been in build rev `2016.11.16.4204`, since it was also a problem on other sites.
>
> After talking to [@NicolasChabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) I've un-hidden the privilege on SO.ru, since you have a custom ad for asking questions. The Reduced Ads privilege is now shown on the /help/privileges page, the help article now also works as expected.